# Euler problem 5

Tags: performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, rust

I am starting to learn Rust and it seems pretty awesome but it's way different than any C based language. I want to know how can I make this code more idiomatic and also how can I improve my solution itself.

[Euler problem 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5).

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

```
fn near_pow(number:f64, exponent:f64)-> f64
{
    exponent.powf(number.log(exponent).floor())
}

fn is_prime(number:i32) -> bool
{
    use std::ops::Rem;
    
    if number == 2 { return true; }
    if number.rem(2)== 0 { return false; }
    
    let mut i = 3;
    while (i*i) <= number
    {
        if number.rem(i) == 0 {return false;}
        i+= 2;
    }
    true
}

fn euler_problem5(to:i32) -> f64
{
    (1..to+1).filter(|&x| is_prime(x))
    .fold(1f64, |p , x|p * near_pow(to as f64, x as f64))   
}
fn main() {
    
    let x = euler_problem5(20);
    println!("{}",x);
    
}
```

[Link to playground](http://is.gd/K7lUdZ)

Comment: You changed the code after you posted it. That makes it kind of difficult to give feedback...

Comment: yes i wasn't sure if i should answer myself or edit. Although i didn't change anything that significant. I am sorry about that.

Comment: *anything that significant* — except you invalidated one of my points. There's no rush to post your question to Code Review; take your time and make sure that the code you submit the first time is the code you want reviewed.

Comment: FWIW, the filter *is* better though!

Comment: yes sir you are absolutely right, I will keep that in mind next time :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rust uses "Egyptian braces" in the majority of cases.

   ```
   if condition {
       // block
   } else {
       // another block
   }
   ```
2. Use a space after a `:` in a type.

   ```
   fn foo(value: type)
   ```
3. Use spaces around operators like `==`, `+`, and `*` and around symbols like `->`.

   ```
   i += 2;
   ```
4. Use a space after a `,`.

   ```
   println!("{}", x);
   ```
5. There's no need to use a `;` in one-line early return statements (*guard clauses*).

   ```
   if number == 2 { return true }
   ```
6. Use the `%` operator instead of calling the `rem` method:

   ```
   if number % 2 == 0 { return false }
   ```
7. Write the closure to `fold` inline, especially since you aren't able to give it a better name than `fold_op` (OP changed the code I am referring to; look in the revision history to see what I'm talking about).

   ```
   (1..to + 1).fold(1f64, |p, x| {
       // stuff
   })
   ```
8. Whenever possible, try to drive out mutability. I also dislike `return` statements inside of loop bodies (or really anywhere that aren't guard clauses). Try to use iterators instead.

All together:

```
fn near_pow(number: f64, exponent: f64) -> f64 {
    exponent.powf(number.log(exponent).floor())
}

fn is_prime(number: i32) -> bool {
    if number == 2 { return true }
    if number % 2 == 0 { return false }

    (0..)
        .map(|v| 3 + 2 * v) // Can use `Range::step_by` when stable
        .take_while(|i| i * i <= number)
        .all(|i| number % i != 0)
}

fn euler_problem5(to: i32) -> f64 {
    (1..to + 1).fold(1f64, |p, x| {
        if is_prime(x) {
            p * near_pow(to as f64, x as f64)
        } else {
            p
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", euler_problem5(20));
}
```

I'm not well-versed on how to do the Euler problems in an efficient way, so hopefully someone else will chime in there.

**Update after the original code changed**

```
fn euler_problem5(to: i32) -> f64 {
    (1..to + 1)
        .filter(|&v| is_prime(v))
        .fold(1f64, |p, x| p * near_pow(to as f64, x as f64))
}
```

**Updates based on other answers**

[user5402](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105935/32521) argues to replace floating point with integer operations, but either way you should probably use *unsigned* integers as you don't need to support negative numbers. This allows you a bit more upper bound to your values as well.

Answer (score 3):

## f64

My biggest critique is that you are using floating point arithmetic to solve an integer problem.

Given the possibility for round off error and inexact answers, I would opt for a simple while-loop to compute `nearest_pow`:

(Sorry - this is Python, I'm not a Rust programmer yet)

```
def nearest_pow(p,n):
  a = 1
  while a*p <= n:
    a = a * p
  return a
```

Rust has `fold` and `take_while`, so I'm sure you can implement this in a functional manner.

This is efficient - it only performs log n iterations - and 
won't suffer from any round-off errors.

Moreover, it also works for big integers which might come in handy for other number theoretic problems.

Also, I would return the answer as an integer value - perhaps a `i64`.

Comment: A reasonable suggestion, integer operations will almost always be faster than floating point. However, a [literal translation of your sample code](http://is.gd/OfN3tx) seems to differ in results...? Maybe the argument order changed?

Comment: You also need to [handle the edge cases](http://is.gd/aqOGD3) of `0` and `1`.

Comment: The OP's is_prime function is returning true for p = 1 which could be considered a problem. Alternatively the main loop could just start at 2.

Comment: Yea you are right forgot about that edge case and I should have started at 2. I knew there was gonna be a lost in precision for big numbers possibly giving a power nearest to x so that x <= b^e,   but would this happen in the range of 32 integers? Also could you say my near_pow function is O(1) ? (I am guessing its probably not).